# How to mock mongodb for python unittests?

Tags: python, mongodb, unit-testing, mocking, pymongo

I am using `mock` module for Python 2.7 to mock my other functions and using

`unittest` for writing unit tests.

I am wondering if mocking the MongoDB is different than using mock functionality (`mock.patch` a function that is being called?) Or I need to use another different package for that purpose?

I do not think I want to have a test mongodb instance running. All I want is some tempo data and being able to call `pymongo` functionality. I am just a bit lost in thinking of is there a way to write a mock for a module (like `pymongo`), or anything is achievable by `mock` module.

So appreciate if you could provide an example or tutorial on this.

### Code to Test

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

monog_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
client = MongoClient(monog_url)
db = client.db

class Dao(object):
   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def save(self, user):
      db_doc = {
        'name': user.name,
        'email': user.email
      }
      db.users.save(db_doc)

   def getbyname(self, user):
      db_doc = {
        'name': user.name,
      }
      return db.users.find(db_doc)
```

To test this, I do not really want a test mongodb up and running! But also, I think I do not want to mock db.userssave and db.users.find because I want to actually be able to retrieve the data that I saved and make sure it is in the db. I think I need to create some **fixtures** per models that are in my memory and work with them. Just do I need an external tool to do so?

I am thinking of keeping some fake data like this, just do not know how to properly deal with it.

```
users = { 
    {'name' : 'Kelly', 'email' : 'kelly@gmail.com'},
    {'name': 'Sam', 'email': 'sam@gmail.com'}
}
```

Comment: Can you add some sample code that you want to test as a base for giving  advise?

Comment: @KlausD. I added a sample code in the description.

Comment: Consider that you may not need to mock any part of the database or stub any of its calls. Instead, have a separate test environment with a test database, and tear the database down after each test run. Allow the app to work naturally when persistence is necessary, and create test doubles for the data returned from the database where persistence is not necessary.

Answer (score 22):

I recommend using mongomock for mocking mongodb. It's basically an in-memory mongodb with pymongo interface and made specifically for this purpose.

https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock

Comment: Do you have any examples that shows how to generate mock data from a mongodb? I could not find any docs/examples for that anywhere.

Comment: You could write a script to fetch the data you want, save it in a json file using bson.json_util.dumps somewhere accessible to your tests and load the data into mongomock in your setUp function or fixture.

Comment: For people who are new to `mongomock`, you can start using it simply by two lines of code: `import mongomock`  `client = mongomock.MongoClient()`. After that you can use `client.my_db.my_coll.insert_one({'a': 1})` exactly the way you're using `pymongo`.

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this if you're just doing something simple, and you don't really need to retrieve by field.

```
@mock.patch("pymongo.collection.Collection.find")
def test_name(self, mock_find):
    mock_find.return_value = {'name' : 'Kelly', 'email' : 'kelly@gmail.com'}
    # rest of test
```

Comment: and what if we want to retrieve it by field ? like object.field ?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly mock PyMongo, but I recommend mocking the MongoDB server itself. I've written a pure-Python emulator for MongoDB that can control fully, which responds to MongoDB Wire Protocol messages however you choose:

http://mockupdb.readthedocs.io/tutorial.html

Here's an example of using MockupDB with a Python application:

https://emptysqua.re/blog/test-mongodb-failures-mockupdb/

It requires intimate knowledge of the MongoDB wire protocol, but that's a useful skill to acquire anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @mirthbottle answer, if you want to access attribute of mongo object as a field you can do it as,

```
class MongoDummybject:
    def __init__(self, _data):
        for _d in _data:
            setattr(self, _d, _data[_d])

return_data = {'name' : 'Nishant', 'email' : 'nishant@gmail.com'}

@mock.patch("pymongo.collection.Collection.find")
def test_name(self, mock_find):
    mock_find.return_value = MongoDummybject(return_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

For unit testing exception wrapped within custom exception, patch functions(e.g.[bulk_write](https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock/blob/03661bd831046ebc88b14fa2fb9c474035e69f88/mongomock/collection.py#L1781)) within [Collection](https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock/blob/develop/mongomock/collection.py#L376) of [mongomock](https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock/tree/develop/mongomock)

```
@mock.patch("mongomock.collection.Collection.bulk_write", side_effect=BulkWriteError({}))
def test_bulk_wrt_err(self, blk_wrt_err):
    with self.assertRaises(SpecialBulkWriteExcep) as context:
        add_user()
```

Sample code [here](https://replit.com/@abhijeetbhanjadeo/mockmongodbexceptionunittest)

Answer (score 1):

[Mongomock](https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock) is recommended way for testing, here's a runnable example to get started:

*client.py*

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

import pymongo

monog_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27018'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(monog_url)
db = client.db


@dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    email: str


class Dao:

    def save(self, db, user):
        db_doc = {
            'name': user.name,
            'email': user.email
        }
        return db.users.insert_one(db_doc).inserted_id

    def get_by_name(self, db, user):
        db_doc = {
            'name': user.name,
        }
        return db.users.find(db_doc)
```

*test_client.py*

```
import mongomock
import pytest

from client import Dao, User


class TestDao:

    @pytest.fixture
    def user(self):
        yield User(name='John', email='test@gmail.com')

    @pytest.fixture
    def dao(self):
        yield Dao()

    @pytest.fixture
    def client_mock(self):
        yield mongomock.MongoClient()

    @pytest.fixture
    def mock_db(self, client_mock):
        yield client_mock.db

    def test_save(self, mock_db, dao, user):
        id = dao.save(mock_db, user)

        users = list(mock_db.users.find())
        assert [obj for obj in users if obj['_id'] == id]
        assert len(users) == 1

    def test_get_by_name(self, mock_db, dao, user):
        dao.save(mock_db, user)
        found_user = next(dao.get_by_name(mock_db, user))
        found_user.pop('_id')
        assert found_user == user.__dict__

        unknown_user = User(name='Smith', email='john@gmail.com')
        found_user = next(dao.get_by_name(mock_db, unknown_user), None)
        assert found_user is None
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [@funnydman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9926721/funnydman) example.

client.py

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient


class MongoDB(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.MONGO_URI ='mongodb://localhost:27018' 
        self.client = MongoClient(self.MONGO_URI)
        self.default_db = self.client.db

    def ingest_one(self, document: any, collection_name: str, db_name: str = None):

        if document:
            db_name = self.client[db_name] if db_name else self.default_db
            return db_name[collection_name].insert_one(document).inserted_id

    def find(self, query: dict, collection_name: str, db_name: str = None):
        db_name = self.client[db_name] if db_name else self.default_db
        return db_name[collection_name].find(query)
```

test_client.py

```py
import mongomock
import pytest
import pytz
import datetime

from dataclasses import dataclass

from db.mongo_db import MongoDB


localtz = pytz.timezone('your_time_zone')


@dataclass
class Client:
    document: dict


class TestMongoDB:

    @pytest.fixture
    def client(self):
        yield Client(document={
            "name": "Juan Roman",
            "requestDate": str(datetime.datetime.now(localtz))
        })

    @pytest.fixture
    def mongo_db(self):
        yield MongoDB()

    @pytest.fixture
    def client_mock(self):
        yield mongomock.MongoClient()

    @pytest.fixture
    def mock_db(self, client_mock):
        yield client_mock.db

    def test_ingest_one(self, mock_db,  mongo_db, client):
        id_client = mongo_db.ingest_one(client.document, mock_db.collection.name, mock_db.name)
        stored_obj = mongo_db.find({'_id': id_client}, mock_db.collection.name, mock_db.name)

        assert [obj for obj in stored_obj if str(obj['_id']) == str(id_client)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Would anyone care to comment on [pytest-mock-resources](https://pytest-mock-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) as a possible answer to this question?

It depends on Docker, which I've got on my dev box, but I'm concerned that it might slow things down since it says it spins it's container up each time.

I'm guessing that Docker allows it to be stateful, but that kinda violates the dao of unit-testing, that tests should be independent and not depend on external resources (even Docker, if possible).

Comments are welcome.