# $sum inside aggregate in mongomock seems not to be working

Tags: mongodb, mongomock

I have an aggregate Mongo query that projects some fields and calculates two other ones using *$sum*. The query works as expected, so I created an unit test for it, and to my surprise the test was failing.

I created a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to test my hypothesis that this was a problem with MongoMock, and it seems to be!

Here is the code:

```
import mongoengine as mongo
from mongoengine import connect
from mongoengine.queryset import QuerySet

class ValuesList(mongo.EmbeddedDocument):
    updated_value = mongo.DecimalField()


class ValuesHistory(mongo.Document):
    name = mongo.StringField()
    base_value = mongo.DecimalField()
    values_list = mongo.EmbeddedDocumentListField(ValuesList, required=False)
    meta = {
        'collection' : 'values_history'
    }

    def __str__(self):
        return 'name: {}\nbase_value: {}\n'.format(self.name, self.base_value)


def migrate_data(new_collection):
    ValuesHistory.objects.aggregate(
        {'$project': {'name': 1,
                     'base_value': {'$sum': ['$base_value', {'$arrayElemAt': ['$values_list.updated_value', -1]}]}
                      }
        },
        {'$out': "{}".format(new_collection)}
    )


def clear_tables_and_insert_test_data(db):
    db.test.values_history.drop()
    db.test.updated_values.drop()
    ValuesHistory(name='first',
                  base_value=100,
                  values_list=[ValuesList(updated_value=5),
                               ValuesList(updated_value=15)]).save()

def run_aggregate_query_with_db(db):
    new_collection_name = 'updated_values'

    migrate_data(new_collection_name)

    new_group = ValuesHistory.switch_collection(ValuesHistory(), new_collection_name)
    aggregated_values = QuerySet(ValuesHistory, new_group._get_collection()).all()
    for value in aggregated_values:
        print(value)

    db.close()
```

A quick explanation about the code above.

*ValuesHistory* is a class that contains a String *name*, a numeric *base_value* and a list of values (*ValuesList* class).

The method *clear_tables_and_insert_test_data* clears the two tables used in this test and inserts some test data.

The query in *migrate_data* method creates a new collection (through the *$out* operator) and the *base_value* of the newly created collection should be the sum of the current value and the last value in the *values_list* list. In my case it should be 115 (being 100 the current value and 15 the last value on the list).

If I run the code using a connection to my local MongoDB, like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = connect('test') # connect to real instance of Mongo
    clear_tables_and_insert_test_data(db)
    run_aggregate_query_with_db(db)
```

I get 115 as a result, which is exactly what is expected.

If I, instead, use a connection to MongoMock:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = connect('test', host='mongomock://localhost') # Connect to MongoMock instance
    clear_tables_and_insert_test_data(db)
    run_aggregate_query_with_db(db)
```

I get 100 as result, which is odd! Looks like the *$sum* operator did not do it's job properly, since the sum of 100 and 15 resulted in 100!

**EDIT**: I also tried using the *$add* operator, but the problem remains the same, yielding 100 when it should be 115.

**TL;DR;**

**Question**: How should I use *$sum* (or *$add*) inside an aggregate pipeline on MongoMock so that it yields the correct value?

Comment: Can you share how you are setting up the mock data for this test please. I quick peruse of the [mongomock source](https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock/blob/9278169d42bb03ab50ce3ea5397efb9723bf3c58/mongomock/aggregate.py#L216-L219) shows to me that there is nothing special going on here and the `$arrayElemAt` is simply being interpreted as a `return array[index]`. So this can only be a matter of the data not being set up exactly like you think it is.

Comment: In short the "completeness" here is actually missing the "mock" part which you are saying comes out differently. But kudos on the rest.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I'm not sure I got your question right. In the example I gave above, I insert the data used for the test. I just refactored the code and edited the question to make it more explicit. Please let me know if it's clear enough now.

Comment: My bad, I clearly missed that. So then at a glance it seems more likely that the `$sum` is actually the issue here. Would need a look at the source but it;s plausible the authors forgot to implement the newer 2.6 usage. Can you try `$add` here instead? That's basically the same thing, but since it's an older operator it's usage is more likely implemented properly.

Comment: @NeilLunn I just tested using $add, but the result is wrongly the same for Mongomock! Just to be sure, I also updated my Mongomock version to the latest 3.14.0 ( I was using 3.12.0) but the 100 result keeps showing up! Finally, I created an [issue on Mongomock project](https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock/issues/473), perhaps we'll get more info from there.

Comment: @NeilLunn I just read that the [issue I opened on Mongomock project](https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock/issues/473) received 3 new commits and is now closed! I'll wait for the next version and hopefully the issue will be fixed. If it does, I'll write an answer to my own problem.

Comment: I just read the comments. My advice would be to look for another mocking library, since that's a pretty uninformed response and if your issue just gets closed like that with no investigation ( and the "generated array" comment is actually laughable ) then I would not consider any maintainer competent enough to actually resolve the issue themselves.

Comment: @NeilLunn Would you please suggest other mocking libraries? A few questions here in SO, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915031/use-mock-mongodb-server-for-unit-test) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239241/how-to-mock-mongodb-for-python-unittests), shows that mongomock is a common choice. It never hurts to know and test different libraries, but so far mongomock has been working for me. In this specific problem I had, the fix was somewhat quick, which I find a good thing, even though the error was in a basic functionality for me. Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem described was, indeed, a bug on Mongomock that existed up to version 3.14.0.

After the original question was posted, I opened [an issue](https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock/issues/473) on Mongomock's github describing the problem. Shortly after it was fixed and version 3.15.0 has been released a few days ago. I ran the code on the question and the issue is now solved for both *$add* and *$sum* operators!

**TL;DR**

Updating to Mongomock 3.15.0 is enough to solve the problem.