# Testing a POST method unit test which inserts data to mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb, unit-testing, flask, pymongo

I want to know how am I supposed to test my code and see whether it works properly. I want to make sure that it stores the received data to the database. Can you please tell me how am I supposed to do that? While I was searching the forum I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239241/how-to-mock-mongodb-for-python-unittests) post but I did not really understand what is going on. here is the code I want to test.

```
client = MongoClient(os.environ.get("MONGODB_URI"))
app.db = client.securify
app.secret_key = str(os.environ.get("APP_SECRET"))


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():

    if request.method == "POST":
        ip_address = request.remote_addr
        entry_content = request.form.get("content")
        formatted_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d/%H:%M")
        app.db.entries.insert({"content": entry_content, "date": formatted_date, "IP": ip_address})
      
    return render_template("home.html")
```

and here is the mock test I wrote:

```
import os
from unittest import TestCase




from app import app


class AppTest(TestCase):
    # executed prior to each test
    def setUp(self):
        # you can change your application configuration
        app.config['TESTING'] = True

        # you can recover a "test cient" of your defined application
        self.app = app.test_client()

    # then in your test method you can use self.app.[get, post, etc.] to make the request
    def test_home(self):
        url_path = '/'
        response = self.app.get(url_path)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    def test_post(self):
        url_path = '/'
        response = self.app.post(url_path,data={"content": "this is a test"})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The `test_post` gets stuck and after some seconds gives an error when reaches `app.db.entries.insert({"content": entry_content, "date": formatted_date, "IP": ip_address})` part. Please tell me also how can I retrieve the saved data in order to make sure it is saved in the expected way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the proper way to do it but I found a solution. After creating a test client `self.app = app.test_client()` the db gets set to `localhost:27017` so I changed it manually as follows and it worked:

```
self.app = app.test_client()
client = MongoClient(os.environ.get("MONGODB_URI"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do using NodeJS, not tested at all in python but the idea is the same.

First of all, find a in-memory DB, there are options like [pymongo-inmemory](https://pypi.org/project/pymongo-inmemory/) or [mongomock](https://pypi.org/project/mongomock/)

Then in your code you have to do the connection according to you environment (production/development/whatever)

Something like this:

```py
env = os.environ.get("ENV")
if env == "TESTING":
  # connect to mock db
elif env == "DEVELOMPENT":
  # for example if you want to test against a real DB but not the production one
  # then do the connection here
else:
  # connect to production DB
```

Comment: for test_post I am getting this error. Why is that? Can you please tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: builtins.tuple: (<class 'pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError'>, ServerSelectionTimeoutError("localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 618a299, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')>]>"), <traceback object at 0>)